# BX Slider with multiple slides showing only shows one slide

Tags: javascript, bxslider

I am using [bxsldier](http://bxslider.com/) and I want to have three slides show at once. Another three will show when the next button is clicked.  Currently the slider is only showing a single slide. How can I get the slider to show multiple slides like in [this example](http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified)

HTML

```
<ul class="bxslider">
              <li><img src="http://placehold.it/244x209" /></li>
              <li><img src="http://placehold.it/244x209" /></li>
              <li><img src="http://placehold.it/244x209" /></li>
              <li><img src="http://placehold.it/244x209" /></li>
              <li><img src="http://placehold.it/244x209" /></li>
              <li><img src="http://placehold.it/244x209" /></li>
            </ul>
```

JS

```
// BX in Programmes
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  minSlides: 3,
  maxSlides: 4,
  slideWidth: 209,
  slideMargin: 10,
  moveSlides: 3,
  mode: 'horizontal'
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.  The class of the slider was a conflict. I changed the class in the html and the js and it works fine now.